# I am unable to decode the file while sending the encoded file from salesforce

Tags: salesforce, box-api

I am able to upload file using Rest API on box from salesforce. However,the file is getting uploaded in encoded format.I am using HTTPRequest class of salesforce.The content Type is getting set properly.

Please let me know how I can decode the file so that I can read the content of file on Box.com.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you upload your files using cUrl and the V2 api?

Here's the link: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file